# Google Spreadsheet: run script on cell value change

Tags: google-apps-script

In a spreadsheet I have two sheets, * and **Calculator**. When I change the value on "*"!B1 (*i.e. cell B1 of sheet* *), I want to run the script: to change (actually clear) the value of "Calculator"!B3 (*i.e. cell B3 of sheet "Calculator"*).

Here's my code. I created it through Spreadsheet > Tools  > Script editor, so it's not an standalone:

*The difference between Version 1 and 2 is that in **Version 1** the **first function is run** and the **second is missed** (vice versa in Version 2), plus one thing I'll detail below.*

### Version 1

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var languageSheet = ss.getSheetByName("*").getSheetName();
  var languageCell = languageSheet.getRange("B1");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var languageCellCheck = sheets.getActiveCell();
  var cookingMethodSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calculator").getSheetName();
  var cookingMethodCell = cookingMethodSheet.getRange("B3");
  var range = e.range;

  if (range == languageCell)
    cookingMethodCell.setValue("A");
}

//function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var languageCell = ss.getSheetByName("*").getRange("B1");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var languageCellCheck = sheets.getActiveCell();
  var cookingMethodCell = ss.getSheetByName("Calculator").getRange("B3");
  var range = e.range;

  if (range == languageCell)
    cookingMethodCell.setValue("A");
//}
```

### Version 2

```
//function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var languageSheet = ss.getSheetByName("*").getSheetName();
  var languageCell = languageSheet.getRange("B1");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var languageCellCheck = sheets.getActiveCell();
  var cookingMethodSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calculator").getSheetName();
  var cookingMethodCell = cookingMethodSheet.getRange("B3");
  var range = e.range;

  if (range == languageCell)
    cookingMethodCell.setValue("A");
//}

function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var languageCell = ss.getSheetByName("*").getRange("B1");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var languageCellCheck = sheets.getActiveCell();
  var cookingMethodCell = ss.getSheetByName("Calculator").getRange("B3");
  var range = e.range;

  if (range == languageCell)
    cookingMethodCell.setValue("A");
}
```

---

When I say "Version 1" I mean I changed the value of "*"!B1 from "Something" to "Whatever", and cell "Calculator"!B3 wasn't changed. Then, using Version 2, I tried the same but got the same result (no change in B3).

The idea of having two functions (same for both versions) is because I don't know if using `ss.getSheetByName("Calculator").getSheetName();` or directly selecting in as in `ss.getSheetByName("*").getRange("B1");` will make a difference. Apparently, it doesn't.

What's and where's the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Going by your variable name `var languageSheet = ss.getSheetByName("*").getSheetName();` it seems that you expect `languageSheet` to actually be a sheet object and not a string. That seems to be reaffirmed `var sheets = ss.getSheets()[0];`

As such you must edit that line to say `var languageSheet = ss.getSheetByName("*")` and the same goes further on with `var cookingMethodSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Calculator")`

Now the real problem:

```
if (range == languageCell)
  cookingMethodCell.setValue("A");
```

this will always return false. You are comparing two different objects. They will never be the same. You need to compare their column and row or A1 notation instead by using something like `range.getColumn()` and `range.getRow()` or `range.getA1Notation()`. Currently it's like you write the number `3` on two pieces of paper and ask if the two pieces of paper are the same thing. They will both have the same value and be comparable, but they will never be the same piece of paper.

Furthermore, going by your code, you are getting the edited range and then you get the active cell which will always be the same cell. So you might as well have the logic be `if (1 == 1)` or more specifically, because you are comparing to range type objects, it's like writing `if (1 == 2)`

**EDIT:** With the things considered in the comments of this answer you are making things more complicated then they need to be. Here is a function that will clear `B1:B3` in `Calculator` only if `B1` in `*` is changed:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var langName = '*'
  var langCell = 'B1'

  var curSheet = e.range.getSheet()

  if (curSheet.getName() === langName) {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === langCell) {
      var cookingMethodSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Calculator')
      var range = cookingMethodSheet.getRange('B1:B3')
      range.clear()      
    }
  }
```

which you can make a little shorter by doing

```
function onEdit(e) {      
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === '*') {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'B1') {

      SpreadsheetApp
        .getActiveSpreadsheet()
          .getSheetByName('Calculator')
            .getRange('B1:B3')
              .clear() 
    }
  }
```

The indentation is there only so the line is not too long.

Comment: I've changed the script with the first part of your answer. How can I solve the second part (_the real problem_)? I don't know that much of coding.

Comment: @alej27 that very much depends on what exactly you wish to accomplish. What did you want to achieve with that `if` statement? Are you checking if the edited range is `B1`? You need to formulate your logic in a way that would make sense. What do you wish to be true? What does this statement prevent? When coding always first ask yourself 1) what is your goal? 2) what is the logic needed to perform the task? 3) what types of variables and objects do you need to work with? 4) what is the syntax to code this? In that order Actual writing of code only comes in in #4 :)

Comment: a) Yes, I'm trying to check if the edited cell is "*"!B1, b) so that if it's true I'll change the value of cell "Calculator"!B3 to "A" (or to none, whatever). C) Hm, it doesn't _prevent_ anything unless we have different definitions of "preventing" haha.

Comment: **[Here's the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Q7fKU6InHZcHlwIG2CuzhqzsHkUsesuKFFg8KmiJQCc)**. You can change its language in * sheet from Spanish to English (and vice versa). The problem is when you do so, the values selected in the dropdown lists of sheet Calculator remains in Spanish (or in English if it was in Spanish). I want to clear the value of the three dropdown lists in sheet Calculator so it doesn't say "Cocido/a" in _Cooking Method_ and instead "Cooked" (available in dropdown after changing language). **HOPE** you can help me, that's it. =)

Comment: Added code to my answer to show how it can be done with less code. Essentially you just want to get the edited range. Then check if the sheet matches up to the one you expect to be edite. If it is we can check if the correct range was edited. If the range is correct then we can clear the values in another range, otehrwise there is no point in continuing with the script. That is what the `if` prevents — execution of code if it was not the expected edit. Then you simply grab the range you want to clear and clear it :) Please consider marking the answer as correct if that is helpful enough

Comment: Of couse! How I wouldn't after all this help? Besides now you've literally given me the code (I noticed you edited the copy I shared hehehe =).