# Google Script to import CSV file from Google Drive to G Sheets when specific cell is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script in my G Sheets that imports a CSV from Google Drive and I have attached it to a clickable button within the workbook. It works great. Here is the script:

```
function myFunction() {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("FileName.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Imported File");
  sheet.getRange('A1:K10000').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

However, I would like to automate the process further by having it run this function when a specific cell is edited. I will run a webhook to automate changing this cell.

So, as a trial run I found a very helpful stackoverflow question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41033282/google-spreadsheet-run-script-on-cell-value-change) and created this code to simply clear the cells:

```
function onEdit(e) {     
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Imported File') {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'L2') {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Imported File");
  sheet.getRange('A1:K10000').clearContent();

    }
  }
}
```

Again, this works great. So my issue is that whenever I put the full original code inside the edit function it does not work. Have I missed something?

```
function onEdit(e) {     
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Imported File') {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'L2') {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("FileName.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Imported File");
  sheet.getRange('A1:K10000').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: create an installable trigger for your onEdit function and it will solve the issue. Tons of questions regarding this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple triggers such as `onEdit()` have `ScriptApp.AuthMode.LIMITED` permissions, so they do not have access to services such as Drive.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/auth-mode#properties):

> **LIMITED**   A mode that allows access to a limited subset of services. This mode occurs when an add-on or a script bound to a document
> executes an onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) simple trigger, except in the case
> described for NONE.

**Solution:**

You can create an installable trigger on the fly, e.g. when the webhook is run like this:

```
function createTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('csvEdit').forSpreadsheet(ss).onEdit().create();
}
```

Run the function manually first to establish the necessary DriveApp permissions. Then the new trigger will work as usual, when L2 cell is edited.

```
function csvEdit(e) {     
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'Imported File') {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === 'L2') {

  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName("FileName.csv").next();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(file.getBlob().getDataAsString());
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Imported File");
  sheet.getRange('A1:K10000').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly well when I'm in the sheet, so thank you Carlos. I've upvoted it as it works. However, Google doesn't seem to register an Integromat cell edit as a user edit and therefore my initial problem still stands. I need to figure out a way to replace a G Sheet with a CSV automatically.