# How to send an email to current manager when google doc update?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The idea is when google doc updated with a new row (client ID, for example) send a letter to the manager of this client. In my doc, I have columns Client ID (1 column) and e-mail (13 column).
This is the code I'm using:

```
function sendEmails() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var startRow = 9 // First row of data to process
    var numRows = sheet.getRange(13,9).getValue(); // Number of rows to process is set by a formula 
    which counts rows COLUMN/ROW

    var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 9, numRows, 1);

    var data = dataRange.getValues();

    for (var i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var emailAddress = row[13];
        var message = 'New client';
        var subject = 'Check';
        MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
```

But this code doesn't work and also it won't send an email with the update. What can I change to fix that problem?
I'm new to programming, please help.

Comment: `The idea is when google doc updated with new row (client ID, for example) send a letter to manager of this client` this does not match your code. You want to run the function manually or set up an `onEdit` trigger so whenever the user adds a new row to send an email?

Comment: Also if the emails are in column `13` then you need to use `12` as the index : `var emailAddress = row[12];`

Comment: You want to run the function manually or set up an onEdit trigger so whenever the user adds a new row to send an email? I want to set up an onEdit trigger, but I have no idea, how this could work. I'm trying different ways. I used 12 as index too, but this doesn't work anyway. But thank you, I'll change this moment

Answer (score 1):

### Explanation:

According to your comment and description, you want to send an email when the user fills in a particular row.

If that's the case, you need an [installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger. To set up an installable trigger, you can either google it or see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327507/11225291) but you can find of relevant resources for that.

- The following script will send an email when you add an email in column **M** (`13th` column) from `8th` row onwards.
- My recommended approach would be to create a checkbox instead, so when the user ticks that checkbox, the email is sent. But that's up to you.

### Solution:

```
function onEditEmail(e){
  const ss = e.source;
  const ar = e.range;
  const shn = "Sheet1"; // put the sheet name of your choice
  const as = ss.getActiveSheet(); 
  const row = ar.getRow();
  const col = ar.getColumn();
  if (as.getName()==shn && row>8 && col == 13){
   const emailAddress = ar.getValue();
   const message = 'New client';
   const subject = 'Check';
   MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);   
  }
}
```

This will only work if you create an installable trigger for `onEditEmail(e)` and also read carefully the explanation I provided in order to make it work.